# How to generate functions around other functions with Rust macros?

Tags: rust, macros

So I'm writing an embeddable VM and one of the things I plan on doing is a Rust API. However, since the API is meant to be only visible to the program embedding the VM, I want to use macros to auto-generate wrappers for functions so that people using the VM don't have to write as much code beyond what's needed.

For example, in the API currently, I would need to do this:

```rust
fn echo(msg: String) {
    println!(msg);
}

fn echo_api(rs: &SurgeState) {
    let msg = rs.get_string();
    echo(msg);
}
```

But what I want to do is something like this:

```rust
fn echo(msg: String) {
    println!(msg);
}

generate_bindings!(echo, String) // There would be an optional ret argument, but that's not in the example
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how a macro is better than writing out `fn echo_api(rs: &SurgeState) { echo(rs.get_string()) }`. It looks to me like you have to specify most, if not all, of those pieces as macro arguments anyway.

Comment: For the use cases of the VM, most functions are going to be from the application the VM is embedded in, so I don't want to make people have to write out more boilerplate. The macro approach at least makes it look more pleasing

Comment: Does it though? Where is e.g. `get_string` to be inferred from in the macro? By the time you lay everything out in the macro it seems like the macro invocation isn't going to be much shorter than writing the function.

Answer (score 0):

I have sense gotten an answer from the Rust discord server. Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=0e5e072cc3141ae4d7069fca37cab4ac

Comment: Another approach: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2d3aa533d91ad47de18b9ee9243bd9af. But please embed the code in the answer, external links are not considered permanent on SO.